# How can I add items to listbox one under the other in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Hi I am doing shopping list and I want to list the items one under the other

```
ListBox1.Items.Add(shp.fruits & vbNewLine & shp.vegetables & vbNewLine & shp.drinks & vbNewLine & shp.snacks & vbNewLine & shp.detergent)
```

this is my code but writes items next each other without space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not insert line breaks in a `ListBox`.

Every item added will be one line.

If you want to add a range of items, try this instead:

```
ListBox1.Items.AddRange({shp.fruits, shp.vegetables, shp.drinks, shp.snacks, shp.detergent})
```

Comment: how am I going to delete all index then ? ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listbox1.selectedindex) doesnt work for it?

Comment: `Listbox1.Items.Clear()` ?

Comment: @AdileCetinkaya please mark MatSnow's answer as answer.